# Dynamic generation of xml files

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I need to generate XML with two dynamic fields with one field being constant and another field being a 16 digits auto-generated number.

The number of XML and size of XML should be configurable. This is basically used for running load testing

Is there a script available to ease this? There is no programming language-specific. So anything should work. Can someone please help or point me in the right direction forward?

Comment: There are masses of different ways of doing this, the choice all depends on your project environment and the tools you have to hand. When you say "auto-generated", is this a simple incremental number?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0+

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:param name="size" select="100000"/>
  <xsl:template name="main">
    <out>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $size">
        <record field1="constant" field2="{.}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```